# Ansible 'register' gives back an empty result

Tags: ansible

I am using an Ansible play book to remotely make an API call, register it as a variable and then write it to a text file on my local host.

```
- name: Find the the tag (register it to HOTFIXTAG)
  shell: curl https://nginx.service.gc.guardicore/version.js -k -s | grep -oE build_.*\' | tr -d \'\"
  register: HOTFIXTAG
```

and get what I want:

```
ok: [mgmt] => {
    "HOTFIXTAG": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "curl https://nginx.service.gc.guardicore/version.js -k -s | grep -oE build_.*\\' | tr -d \\'\\\"",
        "delta": "0:00:00.029626",
        "end": "2020-07-19 17:34:23.577904",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-07-19 17:34:23.548278",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "build_v31_20200610_41620_hf_20200706_1",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "build_v31_20200610_41620_hf_20200706_1"
```

Then using the HOTFIX.stdout to run a specific command on the remote machine which changes the output of
the API call and then

````
- name: Register the new, updated tag to NEWTAG
  shell: curl https://nginx.service.gc.guardicore/version.js -k -s | grep -oE build_.*\' | tr -d \'\"
  register: NEWTAG ```
````

but when i do the second call and register it the NEWTAG.stdout comes back empty

```
   ok: [mgmt] => {
    "NEWTAG": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "curl https://nginx.service.gc.guardicore/version.js -k -s | grep -oE build_.*\\' | tr -d \\'\\\"",
        "delta": "0:00:03.216042",
        "end": "2020-07-19 17:35:01.842620",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-07-19 17:34:58.626578",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": [],
```

and i can't figure out why, any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, Have you executed the command `curl https://nginx.service.gc.guardicore/version.js -k -s | grep -oE build_.*\' | tr -d \'\"` locally to check if there is the desired output generated ?

Comment: not related to thus very problem but you should like to the module `uri` to make http calls

Comment: @error404 the 'curl' command runs remotely on both occasions.
I did went to remote host and run it and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use -vvvv for verbose output . It can help to debug and understand what is not right :)